# OpenSSL RSA Public Key encryption in Java in Server and decryption with Private Key in Client in OSX

Tags: macos, openssl, rsa

I have an application which is client/server based. The client is developed for both iOS and OSX. The server is common for both the clients (and server's implementation cannot be changed).

The client developed in iOS generates an RSA public/private key pair and send the public key in base64 encoding to the server. The server (implemented in Java) encrypts some secure data and sends the same to the client who is required to decrypt data with the private key. The RSA key pair is generated on iOS using the Crypto Exercise Sample provided by apple.

The public and private key generated (of key length 1024) in base64Encoding is of length 216 and 844 bytes respectively and of the form provided below.

```
Private Key:
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

Public Key:

MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADkIJlKBgQDQ1dz/te8wiMP2SMIzP+auw3hBIuAFWBNkkz527gKb3NCYwt4Mfhfpi7Qn0fpcYtEwFqnRSujJIxmTFzjXBB0VsQP+5bRQtUZYBFs8Zna+JDhC+Q1eg0XqeGJIeILrxn9wODdQPO3KJtK0ozqFkfvjfRwphsa5xIYFe4G/cJJ6EQIDAQAB
```

Things are working fine in the iOS world.

I am trying to implement this in the MAC using Objective-c and find that the Crypto Exercise sample is not working as expected. The SecItemCopyMatching is returning failure.

While investigating for the solution found that the public/private key using Open SSL met the criteria of private and public key except for the header and footer that is appended to the generated key pair.

I used the SSCrypto OpenSSL wrapper (http://septicus.com/products/opensource/) to generate the public and private key pair using OpenSSL which is of the form.

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrEgoLjG34pNLj4ahpWlvXZZEh
zimg/mJoKJLdrjE3Fg817Qf2+iXTPMWAtmCkYgHn9Y99VJSdJzrb0/E1JnxMPva5
2ZMS8ilS/hSZnXRAlq2OPFMj64SU9XDu/eWqJMULELNkBcTtPgTCAkjrDU6Qt2Ab
wNUwrgufJC8WJEhWdQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----
```

To extract the public key, I stripped of the "-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----" and "-----END PUBLIC KEY-----" footer and white spaces to extract the public key to be sent to the server.

The problem is that when I strip the header and footer the sent the public key to the server, though the server successfully encrypts the data (using the public key) and sent encrypted data to the client, the decryption using private key (in PEM format) using OpenSSL fails. 
I think the decryption has failed as when i modify the public key's content (by stripping of the header/fooders), the public and private key seize to be key pairs.

Can somebody help me with the solution such that I am able to use the private key to decrypt the received encrypted data.

Alternatively, can somebody help me in generation of public key/private key pair of abovementioned lengths using objective-c api's (pair as generated by OpenSSL) which will fix the issue I am facing?

Thanks & Regards.

The data encrypted by server using Public Key is an AES key. The size of the AES key after encryption using public key is 176 characters. Here is the code snippet which does it.

```
public static String encryptAESKey(byte[] aesKeyBytes, String publicKeyStr) {
    String cipherStr = null; 

    try {
        PublicKey pkey = getPublicKey(publicKeyStr);

        final Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(RSA_ALGORITHM);
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, pkey);

        byte[] cipherBytes = cipher.doFinal(aesKeyBytes);

        cipherStr = Base64.encodeBase64String(cipherBytes);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return cipherStr;
}

private static PublicKey getPublicKey(String publicKey) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {

    KeyFactory rsaKeyFac = KeyFactory.getInstance(RSA_ALGORITHM);
    byte[] keyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(publicKey.getBytes());

    X509EncodedKeySpec keySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(keyBytes);  
    RSAPublicKey rsaPubKey = (RSAPublicKey)rsaKeyFac.generatePublic(keySpec);
    return rsaPubKey;       
}
```

Comment: How much data are you encrypting and what method/s are you using to encrypt it?

Comment: I have updated my earlier post with the requested information. Hope that helps.

Comment: For a 1024 bit public key, you can encrypt about 936 bits (117 bytes).  This should be fine for an AES key on the order of 128 bits.  But 176 characters seems like a lot for an AES key.  But if the size were a problem, I would expect the doFinal() method would throw an exception.

Comment: I am sorry. The size of the AES Key encrypted with the public key comes to 176 characters :). I'll update the earlier post with the correction.

Comment: You should not remove the `-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----` headers.

Comment: But the problem with retaining the  -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY----- headers and footer is that the server java code which does the encryption with the public key fails. I have no option but to remove the header and footer and white spaces and only then will the public key encryption using java code succeed.

Comment: @Mycompuser +1 for shanet comment. You shouldnt remove header and footer, I think your error is coming from your java server

Comment: @Mycompuser just solved this. I could walk you through if you're still interested

Comment: Daniel, Thanks for the reply. Please do post the solution as it might help others.